# Replace string values in pandas rows with numbers with the help of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 10 unique values in one column from my dataframe. For example below is the dataframe

```
df['categories'].unique()
```

output is :

```
Electronic
Computers
Mobile Phone
Router
Food
```

I want to replace 'Electronic' with 1, 'Computers' with 2, 'Mobile Phone' with 3, 'Router' with 4 and 'Food' with 5. The expected output must be

```
df['categories'].unique()
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**I tried looping the df['categories'].unique(), but i'm unable to do that. Can anyone help me with this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```py
new_vals = {'Electronic': 1, 'Computers' : 2, 'Mobile Phone' : 3, 'Router' : 4 , 'Food' : 5}
df = df.replace({'categories': new_vals})
```

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn` provides [similar functionality](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html).

This approach is optimal when you are trying to build a predictive model and the codes do not play a role:

For example, it does not matter to you that: "Computers" category will get a code of '1' or '2' or '5'.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
df['categories'] = enc.fit_transform(X=df[['categories']]).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
df['categories'] = df['categories'].astype('category').cat.codes
```